# polyline array in c# won't run

Tags: c#, arrays, polyline

i am trying to create a polyline array so that the end user can add as many polylines to his canvas as he wants to, the code won't run and wile debugging it writes: "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation."
here is a part of the code

```
Polyline[] linije = new Polyline[10];        
linije[0].Stroke = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Black;           
linije[0].StrokeThickness = 1;        
linije[0].Points = poli.Points;          
canvas1.Children.Add(linije[0]);
```

Comment: On which line do you get the exception. Your code should throw a null reference exception on line 2 of your sample.

Comment: Having declared an array Polyline is not enough. You need to create a Polyline object instance for every slot of your array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a null reference exception because you don't create a Polyline instance in element 0 of your array.

```
Polyline[] linije = new Polyline[10];     
linije[0] = new Polyline();  // Create the Polyline object!!!
linije[0].Stroke = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Black;           
linije[0].StrokeThickness = 1;        
linije[0].Points = poli.Points;          
canvas1.Children.Add(linije[0]);
```

Remember that creating an array of a certain type DOESN'T create the objects for each element in that array. You can easily spot that by using [the debugger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kya29xtx.aspx). If you add a breakpoint just after after the line `Polyline[] linije = new Polyline[10]` and you add a watch for linije[0] you'll see that it is null.